# How to display selected entries of an array of structures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct, printf, display

Suppose we have an array of structure. The structure has fields: `name`, `price` and `cost`.

Suppose the array `A` has size `n x 1`. If I'd like to display the names of the 1st, 3rd and the 4th structure, I can use the command:

```
A([1,3,4]).name
```

The problem is that it prints the following thing on screen:

```
ans = 

    name_of_item_1

ans = 

    name_of_item_3

ans = 

    name_of_item
```

How can I remove those `ans =` things? I tried:

```
disp(A([1,3,4]).name);
```

only to get an error/warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `A([1,3,4]).name`, you are returning a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).  This is equivalent to typing in the following in the MATLAB command prompt:

```
>> A(1).name, A(3).name, A(4).name
```

That's why you'll see the MATLAB command prompt give you `ans = ...` three times.

If you want to display all of the strings together, consider using [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) to join all of the names together and we can separate the names by a comma.  To do this, you'll have to place all of these in a cell array.  Let's call this cell array `names`. As such, if we did this:

```
names = {A([1,3,4]).name};
```

This is the same as doing:

```
names = {A(1).name, A(3).name, A(4).name};
```

This will create a 1 x 3 cell array of names and we can use these names to join them together by separating them with a comma and a space:

```
names = {A([1,3,4]).name};
out = strjoin(names, ', ');
```

You can then show what this final string looks like:

```
disp(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
[A([1,3,4]).name]
```

which will, however, concatenate all of the names into a single string.

The better way is to make a cell array using:

```
{ A([1,3,4]).name }
```